# what can be the item in "import item" in python?

Tags: python, import

I have following hierarchy.

```
A\
  B\
    __init__.py
    testB.py
    C\
      __init__.py
      test1.py
      test2.py
```

when I write following in testB.py

```
import C
test1.func1()
test2.func2()
```

Why I am unable to call the functions defined inside test1.py or test2.py ?

**NOTE:** There is a function called func1 and func2 defined inside test1.py and test2.py respectively.

Comment: What is in your __ init __.py of C?

Comment: Thomas Junk@ its empty file

Comment: Can't you do `from C import test1, test2`?

Comment: @jDo i can do that, but i want to know why above code is not working ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you `import C`, the Python import mechanism doesn't look through your `C` directory and automatically import every ".py" file from that directory.  This saves on memory and time - suppose that directory `C` was a huge package; it wouldn't optimize memory space to import everything.

Instead, do this:

```
from C import test1, test2

test1.func1()
test2.func2()
```

Comment: so do you mean that when I do "import C", it will import all .py file from C ?

Comment: your C directory.  See my answer for more explanation.

Comment: ok, if it import all .py files from C then why I am unable use the functions defined inside them using "test1.func1()" ?

Comment: No - the correct behavior is that `import C` *doesn't* import all ".py" files from directory C.  That's why you are unable to use those functions.  For an explanation why, see my answer above.

Comment: great, then what does "import C" exactly do?

Comment: That would depend on what you have in `C`'s `__init__.py` file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113206/discussion-between-daniel-and-mahendra-vishwakarma).

Comment: its great. lets talk on chat

Answer (score 3):

You probably think about Python imports in a C way. But Python imports work like this:

```
import C.test1
import C.test2
C.test1.func1()
C.test2.func2()
```

or

```
from C import test1, test2
test1.func1()
test2.func2()
```

Comment: so does it means we cant import sub-package directly ?

Comment: `from C import test1` is a "direct" import.

Answer (score 0):

First option: You could add a

```python
from test1 import *
from test2 import *
```

or

```python
from test1 import func1
from test2 import func2
```

(the second option is clearly better, `from ... import *` isn't a good style.)

to the top of the `__init__` file, then you can do

```python
import C

C.func1()
C.func2()
```

The modules are not all just loaded in, they are stored in the "variable" C.

Here is a second option:

Add this to `__init__.py`:

```python
import test1
import test2
```

And use it this way:

```python
from C import *

test1.func1()
test2.func2()
```

or the third option:

Change `__init__.py` like you would do with option 2

use it by

```python
from C import test1, test2

test1.func1()
test2.func2()
```

The third option is better than the second; as `from ... import *` is not a good style.